# Can i reject funds withdrawing from paypal?

Tags: paypal

i did withdrawing money from **paypal**, but now i want to reject it. Can i do it?

I already sent message to resolution center, but i would now if it is possible generally

thanks,
Giorgi

Answer (score 0):

if you caught it within minutes there is a chance you could have called business or customer support to stop it. However you'll have to stop it at your bank unfortunately.